# Automate inactive/unfocussed window

Tags: autoit

Is there any way to run an AutoIt script on a window while it's not on top?

Example : Browsing Facebook, while the script is running on a game that's just behind the browser.

Could I do something like that?

Answer (score 0):

If the game is running in Windowed mode you should be able to get a handle a specific window using it's title with the command [`WinGetHandle`](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/WinGetHandle.htm). Using the returned handle you can then use [`ControlSend`](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/ControlSend.htm) to send various text and keys to the window.

It's hard to help you more than that, you question is very vague. If you provide more details on what exactly you want to accomplish we might be able to help you more.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to have to agree with Bibz answer. This question needs to be revised to provide a little more detail on what you're trying to do. The answer to this would really depend on the game and how it's running. For example: A web-based game such as one at coolmath-games.com. These games seem to be mostly Adobe FLASH based games that operate in the web browser. Another example would be Minecraft. This game is operating via it's own window. My last example would be a game like World of Warcraft which operates in a full-screen window. Using AutoIt to automate any processes would vary greatly in all of these situations.

If you want to use AutoIt on a game in the background while you browse the web or perform any other functions, your best bet would be to use [WinGetHandle](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/WinGetHandle.htm) and [ControlSend](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/ControlSend.htm) like Bibz recommended. Be sure to avoid using the [Send()](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/Send.htm), [MouseClick()](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/MouseClick.htm), or similar functions as this would disrupt your browsing.

Check out this example below. It opens an instance of Internet Explore, navigates to Google, then searches for a term, all in the background. At the end of the script, I set it to make the browser visible so you can see that the search was in fact completed.

```
#CS
    This example opens up a webpage in the background, navigates to Google,
    and searches something.
#CE

#include <GUIConstants.au3>
#Include <IE.au3>

$a = "THIS IS WHAT I'M GOOGLING"
Preview($a)

Func Preview($Submit = "")
    $oIE = _IECreate ("http://www.google.com", 0, 0)
    $oForm = _IEFormGetObjByName ($oIE, "f")
    $oQuery = _IEFormElementGetObjByName ($oForm, "q")
    _IEFormElementSetValue ($oQuery, $Submit)
    _IEFormSubmit ($oForm)
    Sleep(3000)
    MsgBox(0,"Showing IE","Now making IE visible",3)
    _IEAction($oIE,"visible")
EndFunc

#CS
    Notice, the browser is being used to Google something, then it's becoming visible AFTER the search was done.
#CE
```

I hope this help!

Thanks,

Tim